# Random Samples and Sample Variance Bound

Tags: probability, statistics, convergence-divergence, random-variables

Let $X_{1}, X_{2}, \dots, X_{n}$ be a random sample from a population. Show that:

$$\max_{1 \leq i \leq n}|X_{i}-\bar{X}|<\frac{(n-1)}{\sqrt{n}}S$$

Where we have the sample variance $S^{2}=\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_{i}-\bar{X})^{2}$, unless all $n$ observations are equal or $n-1$ of the $X_{i}$'s are equal.

---

I'm not sure on how to begin with the exercise. Maybe one could use one of the convergence theorems (weak law of large numbers or central limit theorem) and obtain a bound depending on $n$? What would be a good way to get started?

Comment: Sorry, bad wording.

Comment: Are you sure about $n-1/\sqrt{n}$? Can you check the $\sqrt{}$ please?

Comment: Yes, completely sure about it. Would it be simpler without the square root?

Comment: Hm, no not easier. I was trying something but did not work out.

Comment: I have $(n-1)S^2$ (from rearranging the formula for $S^2$), so when I take the root, I get $\sqrt{n-1}S$ and not $(n-1)S$, that is why I asked.

Comment: Actually I proved that $$\max|X_i-\bar X|\ge \frac{n-1}{\sqrt{n}}S^2$$ but this does not help very much. But then for your inequality to hold, we must have $$\frac{n-1}{\sqrt{n}}S^2<\frac{n-1}{\sqrt{n}}S \implies S^2<S \implies S<1$$ So, are you sure about your inequality and your assumptions? Sorry, for asking again.

Comment: Let $a_i=X_i-X$ and WLOG, suppose $\max |a_i|=|a_n|$. Note than $\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i=0$. The inequality can be rewritten as $$\frac{(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}a_i)^2}{(n-1)^2}\le \frac{(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}a_i^2)}{(n-1)}$$ which holds ($||a||_{1}\le ||a||_{2}$)

Comment: I'm sure of the assumptions and the inequality, the term that causes trouble for me would be the $\sqrt{n}$ (if it's not there, then this follows by Cauchy-Schwarz). I think I may be missing something important.